# How to bin a continuous variable while keeping its numeric feature in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I like to bin a continuous `numeric` variable while keeping it `numeric`. There are several options to discretionize or categorize a continuous variable in a `factor` variable, like this:

```
data(mtcars)

library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(mpg_binned = cut_width(mpg, 2, closed = "right", boundary = 10))
as_tibble(mtcars %>% select(mpg, mpg_binned))

# A tibble: 32 × 2
     mpg mpg_binned
   <dbl> <fct>     
 1  21   (20,22]   
 2  21   (20,22]   
 3  22.8 (22,24]   
 4  21.4 (20,22]   
 5  18.7 (18,20]   
 6  18.1 (18,20]   
 7  14.3 (14,16]   
 8  24.4 (24,26]   
 9  22.8 (22,24]   
10  19.2 (18,20]   
# … with 22 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

But I like to do various graph and operations with numerics further on. Thus I like to convert each initial value to the center of that interval. First observation remains 21, since it is the middle of (20,22]. Rounding does not work, because row 7 value 14.3 should become 15 (the middle of (14,16]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split the `mpg_binned` column into runs of digits and take the average, with something like:

```
mtcars$mid <- sapply(stringr::str_extract_all(mtcars$mpg_binned,"[0-9]+"), 
                     function(x){mean(as.numeric(x))})
```

Comment: I was looking for a more direct tidyverse approach, but the workaround does the job.

Comment: @Marco this approach can be re-written in a {tidyverse} sense: `mtcars %>% mutate(mid = map_dbl(str_extract_all(mpg_binned,"[0-9]+"), ~ mean(as.numeric(.x))))`

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the lower and upper bounds from `mpg_binned` with `tidyr::extract()`, and average them.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  extract(mpg_binned, c("low", "up"), "(\\d+),(\\d+)", remove = FALSE, convert = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(mid = (low + up) / 2)

# # A tibble: 32 × 4
#    mpg_binned   low    up   mid
#    <fct>      <int> <int> <dbl>
#  1 (20,22]       20    22    21
#  2 (20,22]       20    22    21
#  3 (22,24]       22    24    23
#  4 (20,22]       20    22    21
#  5 (18,20]       18    20    19
#  6 (18,20]       18    20    19
# # … with 26 more rows
```